# New column with percentage change in R

Tags: r, dataframe

How do I make a new column in DF with the percentage change in share price over the year?

```
DF <- data.frame(name = c("EQU", "YAR", "MOWI", "AUSS", "GJF", "KOG", "SUBC"),
                 price20 = c(183, 343, 189, 88, 179, 169, 62),
                 price21 = c(221, 453, 183, 85, 198, 232, 67))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a line that will do it for you. I've also added a round function to it so the table is more readable.

```
DF$percent_change <- round((DF$price21 - DF$price20) / DF$price20 * 100, 2)


  name price20 price21 percent_change
1  EQU     183     221          20.77
2  YAR     343     453          32.07
3 MOWI     189     183          -3.17
4 AUSS      88      85          -3.41
5  GJF     179     198          10.61
6  KOG     169     232          37.28
7 SUBC      62      67           8.06
```

Answer (score 0):

This line should do it:

```
DF$change <- (DF$price21/DF$price20*100) - 100
```

Answer (score 0):

We can use a simple division and `scales::percent`:

```
library(dplyr)

DF %>% mutate(percent_change = scales::percent((price21-price20)/price20))

  name price20 price21 percent_change
1  EQU     183     221         20.77%
2  YAR     343     453         32.07%
3 MOWI     189     183         -3.17%
4 AUSS      88      85         -3.41%
5  GJF     179     198         10.61%
6  KOG     169     232         37.28%
7 SUBC      62      67          8.06%
```

Comment: Do you know how I can make a dataframe that contains only data with growth above 20% ?

Comment: Just use a method for a numeric `percent_change`, as in the answer by @mark_1985, and pipe that result into dplyr::filter: `DF %>% filter(percent_change > 20)`

Comment: Thanks, this helps a lot! How can I sort DF according to percentage growth?

Comment: The comments section is not suited for multiple follow-up questions. For further questions, consider searching other SO questions or maybe open a new question

Comment: Allright, thanks. Im new to this, its helpful with some guidance.